# Doxygen not reading code guarded with macro

Tags: doxygen

I am using doxygen to generate html help for our C++ API.

There are parts which are enabled/disabled in code such as

```
#ifdef EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURE1
class Experimental1
{
   ...
}
#endif

#ifdef EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURE2
class Experimental2
{
   ...
}
#endif
```

I set my doxygen PREDEFINED as follows:

PREDEFINED  = EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURE1 EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURE2

This however doesn't cause doxygen to extract doc. for these classes. Log shows that doxygen reads the files.

Is the syntax for PREDEFINED correct (separated by space and without =)?

How can I debug this?

Comment: Funny… I have this problem just the other way around. Doxygen “sees“ code guarded by `#ifdef DEBUG_SOMETHING` and polutes the referencegraph of functions by occurences that are only meant for debugging and would never be there in release code. I have not given any of this `DEBUG_SOMETHING` macros in any of doxygens configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look into the doxygen manual:

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html

The typical syntax is:

```
PREDEFINED = "name1=value1" \
  "name2=value2" \
  "name3=value3"
```

In more detail the manual says:

> The argument of the tag is a list of macros of the
>   form: name or name=definition (no spaces). If the deﬁnition and the "=" are omitted, "=1" is assumed.
>   To prevent a macro deﬁnition from being undeﬁned via #undef or recursively expanded use the := operator
>   instead of the = operator.

If you have no value you can simply write "name" - so your example should work.

Make sure that the following settings are correct within your doxyfile:

```
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES=NO
EXTRACT_ALL=YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES=YES
```

Otherwise classes aren't put into the documentation.

Also make sure ENABLE_PREPROCESSING is set to YES.

If all this doesn't help please post a minimal example that reproduces the problem.